# findbugs-maven-plugin for project to work with JDK 1.6 1.7 and 1.8

Tags: java, maven, java-8, maven-plugin, java-6

I have just uplift my java project from using JDK 1.6 to JDK 1.8.

My maven build fails when i am performing maven:site lifecycle.

Error stack:

`java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: edu/umd/cs/findbugs/FindBugs2 : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`

My team want me to get this project running on JDK 1.8. But i am not able to find the issue around findbug. Can you help me in getting compatibility info in making the maven plugin : `findbugs-maven-plugin`  Currently i am using version `3.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

Unsupported major.minor version means that you are trying to run class compiled for newer version of Java. Findbug works with Java 1.7 and newer, probably you have both 1.6 and 1.8 on your machine and running maven on 1.6. To check that run 'mvn -version' and set JAVA_HOME environment variable to correct location.

Comment: I don't think that is the case.At times i may want to run the same project in Java 1.6 environment and other time in Java 1.8 . I do set the JAVA_HOME parameters w.r.t. the version I am working on. So as with maven also. What i want to know is that which is the compatible version of findbug maven plugin for Java 6 7 8

Comment: And also to add up, findbug plugin can analyze programs compiled for any version of Java, from 1.0 to 1.8.